# Autumn Blaze maple looks terrible, could it be overwatered, underwatered, or a separate issue

Tags: watering, maple

My autumn blaze maples, planted about a month ago, got exposed to massive rainstorms right after planting. We’ve been trying to compensate, but can’t determine if they are overwatered, underwatered, or having a separate issue entirely.[image]

Comment: Looks like root rot. How does the soil feel ?  Can you attach a photo of the soil .Can you change the potting mix?

Comment: Its not likely to be root rot if they've only been planted for  about a month.... What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Utah zone 4(ish)